# Spring MVC: Right place to talk to database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-boot

Working on some Spring Boot tutorials which are exposing me to some Spring projects like Spring-Data.
Here is a controller method which gets the customer data, saves it to the database and then returns all the saved customers in a list:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitCustomer(@ModelAttribute Customer customer, Model model) {
        System.out.println("First name is "+customer.getFirstName());
        repository.save(customer);
        List<Customer> customers = repository.findAll();
        System.out.println("Length is "+customers.size());
        model.addAttribute("customers", customers);
        return "result";
    }
```

I am not sure about calling `repository` in the controller class.

- Should I move it to `Customer` bean and use `customer.save()` or `customer.getAll()`?
- Should I create a `CustomerDAO` class which will talk to database?

Comment: Take a look at [Spring Data Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories). 

You can have a customerRepository with a save method. So it's OK IMHO to call repository method from a controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fine to call Repository directly from the controller. What you could possibly do is to create [service layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) which would use the repositories to talk to database in order to perform some complex actions.

Such complex action could be for instance saving edits to a customer while also creating audit log entries and updating some entities associated with the customer. Actions like this should typically be atomic and so the service layer is often the place where transaction control logic is applied.

> Should I create a CustomerDAO class which will talk to database?

In this context the repository represents DAO or Data Access Object, so no.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a module preferably in Apache Maven that will contain all your DAOs. DAO is the best approach for communicated with databases. The save() and getAll() should be contained in the DAO. Once you implement your DAO, you should inject the DAO within the submitCustomer() class.